# Given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ and f linear, find bases $\hat{u},\hat{w}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $(f:\hat{u},\hat{w})=A.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be linear, whose corresponding matrix with respect to the standard base $\hat{e}$ is: 
>   $$(f:\hat{e},\hat{e})=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> 1 & 1 & 0\\
> 1 & 1 & 2\\
> 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array} \right).$$
>   Find bases $\hat{u},\hat{w}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that:$$(f:\hat{u},\hat{w})=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> 1 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 1 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array} \right).$$

**Attempt.** If $\hat{u}=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\},~\hat{w}=\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ are the bases then: $$w_1=f(u_1)=f(ae_1+be_2+ce_3)=af(e_1)+bf(e_2)+cf(e_3)=a(1,1,0)+b(1,1,0)+c(0,2,1)$$ and we get a sysetm of 3 equations and $6$ unknowns, $a,b,c,$ and the coordinates of $w_1$. Is there anothet way to approach the problem, or am I on the right path?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The standard way would be to look for eigenvectors.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 Looking for eigenvectors doesn’t help here because the two matrices aren’t similar. Compute the image and kernel of $f$ and remember that the columns of its matrix are the images of the basis vectors.

Comment: It helps a lot. The eigenvectors are (-1,1,0) for eigenvalue 0, (-2,0,1) for eigenvalue 1 and (1,1,0) for eigenvalue 2. So if we take $\hat{u}=((1,1,0), (-2,0,1),(-1,1,0))$ and $\hat{w}=( (2,2,0), (-2,0,1),(-1,1,0))$, we obtain the required matrix.